# take input and match the corresponding file

Tags: java, file, input

I have 100 files named "1.exe","2.exe","3.exe",...,"100.exe"
I want to take input from user as 1,2,3,... or 100 and run the corresponding exe file.
For example if user inputs 45 , I will run file "45.exe"
I don't want to use ifs or switches.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: why do u not want to use switch case

Comment: That's very litte information and thus it's hard to answer that question. However, what about using a map?

Comment: Why do you have a 100 exe's numbered? I assume you don't want the user to be able to run other programs?

Comment: Try 45 +".exe" - and use with process builder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( input + ".exe" ).waitFor();
```

will work if you want to to wait for it.

Answer (score 13):

If the input is always equal to the filename of your exes you can do it with:

```
if( isInputNumberBetween1And100() )
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( input + ".exe" );
```

Comment: you might then want to sanitize your input (test it contains only a number between 1 and 100) for safety reason

Answer (score 2):

If they're in the same folder, you can use also use java.nio.file.Paths to resolve them with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Paths.get(getNumberInput() + ".exe").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

My java is a little rusty, forgive me, but this should give you the idea:

Form a string by doing something like this:

```
String number = "45"; // or whatever user inputs
String suffix = ".exe";
String file = number + suffix;
```

Then once you have the string, use it to run a process:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = rt.exec(file);
```

And when you're done with the process, destroy it:

```
p.destroy();
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Comment: If you're not writing a loop but rather doing an obvious addition, the compiler will optimize it for you anyways - just `+` is fine and will automatically benefit from potential future improvements.

Comment: Again, my java's a bit rusty. Thanks for the feedback!!